# Payment method on my Apple ID

Tags: iphone

Every time I put in my mobile phone as my payment method, it keeps telling me either it has been inserted before (but it doesn't work, like I can't download any apps or make any purchases although I have payed my mobile bill) or it would say that my request to "buy" has been declined although I am not trying to buy anything, I'm just trying to download a FREE app. what should I do?

Comment: Payment methods are no longer required to use the App Store for free 'purchases' (in Canada and US at least). Try just removing all payment methods. Beyond that, I'd recommend engaging Apple support.

Comment: why you need to add a phone as payment method if you are downloading the free app. Put the payment method None on your Apple ID and try it.

Comment: It’s a very common misconception that downloads are not purchases. You can sign out and then try to download, but if Apple asks for a payment method, you have to enter one and it has to be valid and funded. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140496/app-store-constantly-tries-to-charge-me-for-nothing